# Matrix equation confusion

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have to solve the following [matrix equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Jr4.png)

$$X(A - A^T + E) = A^{-1}$$

where $E$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix and $A$ is the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2&3&2\\0&1&2\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Any idea on how to solve it? I would like a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: What's $E{}{}$?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli $E$ is the notation for identity matrix in german speaking areas (E = einheit).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli 3x3 identity matrix

Comment: @Andrei Not rly sure how...

Comment: Are you realized that the computation you have to do is : $X=A^{-1}(A-A^T+E)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie explanation please ....

Comment: @JeanMarie not -400 ... i don't know how to use the formatting properly... + that was for other math problem lol

Comment: Explanation: **Right**-multiply LHS and RHS by $(A-A^T+E)^{-1}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie and I am a little confused when should i Right multiply or left multiply

Comment: Example: if I have $XA=B$, I have to right-multiply: $XAA^{-1}=BA^{-1}$ in order that the next step is $X=...$. Had I used left-multiplication $A^{-1}XA=A^{-1}B$, I can do nothing because $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are not neighbours and the multiplication of matrices is not commutative.

Comment: @john In math.SE no one will _do the calculations for you_ and is not very polite to ask that ( unless few cases when you show your own work and have difficults in the specific problem )

Comment: @JeanMarie so basically when I am multiplying they have to stay one to the other?

Comment: (related to the example I just gave) Non commutativity forbids you to consider that $A^{-1}XA$ is the same as $XA^{-1}A$ which *is* equal to $X$ because, as you formulate it, $A$ and $A^{-1}$ stay one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
 Find the matrix $B := A - A^T + E$ so you will have the equation

> $$XB = A^{-1}$$

Find $A^{-1}$. See if $B$ is invertible, i.e., see if $\det(B) \neq 0$ and then find $B^{-1}$ Such that you can use

> $$XBB^{-1} = XE = X = A^{-1}B^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Left-multiplying both sides of the matrix equation by $\mathrm A$, we obtain

$$\mathrm A \mathrm X (\mathrm A - \mathrm A^{\top} + \mathrm I_3) = \mathrm I_3$$

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides of the matrix equation above, we obtain a linear system of $9$ equations in $9$ unknowns

$$((\mathrm A^{\top} - \mathrm A + \mathrm I_3) \otimes \mathrm A) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) = \mbox{vec} (\mathrm I_3)$$

whose augmented matrix is

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} \mathrm A & -3 \mathrm A & -2 \mathrm A & \mathrm e_1\\ 3 \mathrm A & \mathrm A & -2 \mathrm A & \mathrm e_2\\ 2 \mathrm A & 2 \mathrm A & \mathrm A & \mathrm e_3\end{array}\right]$$